# Heliocentic in c#

Tags: c#, orbit

So perhaps, you've generated some fancy text, and you're content that you can now copy and paste your fancy text in the comments section of funny cat videos, but perhaps you're wondering how it's even possible to change the font of your text? Is it some sort of hack? Are you copying and pasting an actual font?

```
                            days++;
                earth++;
                mars++;

                earth %= 365;
                mars %= 687;
            }

            Console.Write(days);
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.ReadLine();

            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering - what is the specific question here? You've shown sample input and output, but no actual output or explanation of what is wrong.

Comment: Describe the problem; why is the program "not complete"?  You might write a little `ToString()` to output all the variables for troubleshooting. I don't see where/how "N lines" of input are getting in.

Comment: Would this just be a "calculate the beat frequency" problem.  Rather than working in periods, work in frequencies and the algorithm is simple

Comment: You realize that if, say `earth` is 0, then adding 1 to it will never make earth zero again.  You should not be adding *one* to earth and mars every time through the loop. You should be adding *365* to earth and mars every time through the loop! You will get your answer 365 times faster that way!

Comment: That is, your program loop could simply be `int days = 0; while (days % 687 != 0) days += 365;` -- there is no need to track `earth` or `mars` at all.

Comment: Now, there is an easier way than that to solve this problem.  What do you know is true *if the two periods are coprime integers*?  For example, suppose they are 21 and 65, or 8 and 19, or any pair where there are no prime factors in common to both sides?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're only missing a way to process the sample input. It sounds like it's coming in "lines", but that's not really defined, so in this example I'm just using an array. I'm ignoring the fact that the first item specifies the number of testcases, since in this implementation the number is calculated.

Basically I'm just walking through the array, grabbing two items at a time (skipping the first one), and using those values for `earth` and `mars`. The rest is mostly your code (except some changes to outputting to the console):

```
int[] sampleInput = {5, 0, 0, 364, 686, 360, 682, 0, 1, 1, 0};
int n = 1;

for (var i = 1; i < sampleInput.Length - 1; i += 2)
{
    int earth = sampleInput[i];
    int mars = sampleInput[i + 1];
    int days = 0;

    while (earth != 0 || mars != 0)
    {
        days++;
        earth++;
        mars++;

        earth %= 365;
        mars %= 687;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Case {n}: {days}");
    n++;
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: not sure how you figured out what the need was, but nicely done

Comment: @Jawad Yeah, the initial `1` in the sample input threw me, but otherwise the values lined up with the expected output.